# Pay Rise below Inflation while being sold to another Company directly

Tags: salary, negotiation

My yearly pay rise was 1,4% while inflation is at ~8,5%.
So practically my compensation was cut by 7%.

Since my work is directly sold to another company (buddy leasing), my employer could increase my price to the client and give me the full 8,5% rise.

Said client is asking for more professionals like me, so the demand is high. Therefore it is likely that the client will accept the rise.

Due to lack of transparency, i do not even know if my employer did rise the prices or not. For all i know, my employer might have adjustet my price by 8,5%, arguing that they have to adjust my salary and then my employer keeps the 7%.

Is it common to accept a pay rise below inflation?
Should i negotiate hard on this or not?

---

Update:
I negotiated my rise and easily changed it to 5%.
So it is worth negotiating a below inflation rise with the arguments provided in the answers here.

Comment: Whether you accept a pay raise or negotiate harder is something you have to decide for yourself. We have no way of knowing your company or your situation as well as you do. In the end, what matters is whether you can get another job elsewhere that pays as much or more as your current position. Again, you are the best judge for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funnily enough, I'm in an extremely similar situation myself (Pay rise far below inflation).

Here is how I'm currently handling it:

1: Outlining exactly what my Salary was and what inflation is and that anything less than inflation is a de-facto pay cut.
2: Outlining a business case of all the duties I currently perform, including all the ones that are outside of my official role (there's a number of them).
3: Outlining the cost to replace me (looking at average salary for someone with similar skills/experience based on a range of websites).

Finally, putting that all together - it will cost less to the business both in short-term and long-term to pay me more than it would be for me to leave and have someone replace me.

I'll let you know if it works...

Comment: 3.1 Outlining the cost to replace me in regards to the length of the onboarding process for a new hire until they are fully productive and until they aquired the necessary knowledge in the respective business domains, mentioned duties and possible lagacy projects etc..

Comment: Pretty much everyone is in this same situation. Don’t forget the companies are also making 8.5% less. inflation equally affects the company. Doesn’t change the fact this is sound advice

Comment: @Donald Why are the companies making 8,5% less? Prices have risen, so companies selling products/services are not making 8,5% less. They have forwarded costs to the customers. So how do they make 8,5% less?

Comment: @AndreschSerj : we can't charge our customers the full cost of inflation as soon as it happens. And if you try, there's always a 'smart' one that will try and reduce everything he can to look cheaper or average. On one end, not all persons can afford a big raise/inflation, as their income remains the same. On the other end, we often can't take the hit alone.

Comment: @AndreschSerj - Inflation hits companies just as much as it  hits consumers. Employees are ultimately consumer.  So it's not that employees are necessary making 8.5% less, it's that prices have increased for everyone, companies might have increased prices but they are not recouping 100% of the additional costs for goods.

Comment: @iLuvLogix - Ah yes, I did include a section like that in my email - since I've been with my current company a long time through various organizational changes, I have a lot of knowledge of skeletons in closets.

Comment: @Donald Labor is a cost. Companies are forced to pay higher prices for energy, material and services. They will also have to pay higher prices for labor. If Labor is the only price not increasing, then recession is completely handled by the work force.
That seems unfair.

Comment: @OldPadawan you are right. Still, if we do not raise our prices with inflation, companies will continue to make profits while we lose money. I think the scenario where the company makes less profits due to inflation and i make the same money regardless is the favorable option :-D

Comment: @AndreschSerj - Everything is increasing, and labor is increasing, just not at the same rate, hence the reason for inflation or a full blow recession. Life is also not fair nor is it required to be.

Answer (score 4):

> Is is common to accept a pay rise below inflation? Should i negotiate hard on this or not?

Bear in mind that this isn't really a negotiation - your employer has set a new salary for you.  They have informed you of the change and likely won't expect to have entered a debate.  Rather than announcing that you reject their attempt to give you more money, you should ask open questions about how the value was determined.

There are a few possible reasons for being offered a below inflation raise:

1. The company is struggling and can't afford anything more.
2. The company is cheap and/or consciously exploiting you.
3. The market value for your skills has dropped.  Either because there is less need for them, or a bigger pool of people are now available.
4. You aren't performing at the level expected for your salary.  Employment law, or your boss being nice means that it is easier to adjust this slowly over several years rather than dismissing you.

If you are given an answer that the company can't afford more, your options are to suck it up or start looking for a new job.  If the answer is that the company doesn't think you are offering good value for money, ask for specific goals for improvement.  In the other cases, you could choose to follow up in the style suggested by [TheDemonLord](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/190767/112424)

Answer (score 2):

> Is is common to accept a pay rise below inflation? Should i negotiate hard on this or not?

You can always negotiate, but that doesn't mean that the company will budge in any way.  If you feel that your pay ( regardless of a raise ) is not sufficient for the work that you are doing at this company and are confident that you can receive better pay elsewhere then it may be time to start looking for a new company to work for.

Of course, in the meantime, assuming you still have bills to pay, it would make the most sense to accept the pay raise, however unsatisfactory it may be, while you actively pursue a new opportunity.

Comment: As mentioned in my update, it was also possible to negotiate a higher rise :-D